# How do you configure the Vim plugin YouCompleteMe to read a Makefile?

Tags: c++, qt, vim, plugins, makefile

I am trying to get [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) running with my Qt project.  The problem is, I have a lot of sub-projects (hundreds) that all have different compiler flags.  Because of this, one global `.ycm_extra_conf.py` is not sufficient.  Each sub-project has a `Makefile` (generated by `qmake`)containing all of the compiler flags to be passed to GCC.

Is it possible to configure [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) to read the `Makefile` of the project instead of needing to create a different `.ycm_extra_conf.py` for each one?

Comment: How about asking on the plugin's issue tracker?!

Answer (score 1):

Until a better solution comes along, I wrote this ugly Bash script that gets the job done.  You'll need to set the directories to recurse at the top if you're going to use it:

```
#!/bin/bash
    declare -a dirs_to_recurse=('project1' 'project2' 'project3')

template_file="ycm-template.txt"

generate_ycm_config ()
{
    file=.ycmtmp.txt
    dir=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        cd "$dir"
        if [ -f "Makefile" ] && $(ls -U *.pro > /dev/null 2>&1); then
            list=""
            for i in DEFINES CXXFLAG INCPATH; do
                list="${list} '$(cat Makefile | grep "$i.*=" | sed -e "s/$i.*= //g" | sed -e "s/ \$(DEFINES)//g" | sed -e "s/ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs//g" | sed -e "s/ /\', \'/g")', "
            done
            echo "$list"
            rm -f $file
            preifs="$IFS"
            IFS=''
            while read line; do
                echo $line >> $file
                if [[ $line =~ ^compilation_database_folder ]]; then
                    read -r -d '' VAR << __EOF__

flags = [
$list
]

__EOF__
                    echo "$VAR" >> $file
                fi
            done < $template_file
            mv $file .ycm_extra_conf.py
            IFS=$preifs
        fi
    fi
}


for dir in ${dirs_to_recurse[@]}; do
    for i in $(find $HOME/$dir -type d 2> /dev/null); do
        generate_ycm_config "$i"
    done
done
```

And here is my template file:

```
import os
import ycm_core
from clang_helpers import PrepareClangFlags

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''


if compilation_database_folder:
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None


def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return flags
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def FlagsForFile( filename ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    final_flags = PrepareClangFlags(
        MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
            compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
            compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ ),
        filename )
  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```